# UseQueryResult is not a member of mysqlpp

Tags: c++, mysql, mysqlpp

That's the error I get when I run this code :

```
if(mysqlpp::UseQueryResult  res = conn.query(sql).use())
```

Whats more interesting is that the next line doesn't have any problems

```
while(mysqlpp::Row row = res.fetch_row())
```

Really driving me crazy. I've even manually included result.h

I tried all combos of these

include result.h, mysql++.h, connection.h

Comment: What's the definition of `mysqlpp`? And other things you're using, and their types.

Comment: mysqlpp is just the namespace. I checked UseQueryResult is in the mysqlpp namespace in result.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you're using an old version of MySQL++?  The `StoreQueryResult` class used to be called `Result` [before version 3.0.0](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/userman/breakages.html#api-3.0.0).

**Edit:**  Er...  and `UseQueryResult` used to be called `ResUse`, which is a bit more relevant to your error message.